# Limit $.get() requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I defined a function that performs a get request every time a key is pressed:

```
$('.form-control').keypress(function() {
    var o = $('#origin').val();
    var d = $('#destination').val();

    $('#directions').html('Wait, please...');

    $.get('/search', { origin: o, destination: d })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#origin-info').html($('#origin').val());
            $('#destination-info').html($('#destination').val());

            $('#directions').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

However, this is very inefficient because it performs the whole get request every time I press a key. I don't want to go through all the requests while the user is typing. The logical thing would be to limit the amount of requests given an amount of time or setting a timer. And then when the users stops typing the last request would be performed.

I gave a look to the jQuery docs for `get()` but I didn't see such an option.

What would be the best way to do this and how should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea. You didn't see it in the docs for `get` because it's not its job, it's a job for your code *calling* `get`:

```
var timer = 0;
$('.form-control').keypress(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(handleKeypress, 200);
});
function handleKeypress() {
    var o = $('#origin').val();
    var d = $('#destination').val();

    timer = 0;

    $('#directions').html('Wait, please...');

    $.get('/search', { origin: o, destination: d })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#origin-info').html($('#origin').val());
            $('#destination-info').html($('#destination').val());

            $('#directions').html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

There, we start with a `timer` variable with the value `0` (as `0` is an invalid timer handle `clearTimeout` will [silently ignore](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-cleartimeout)). When the user presses a key, we clear any previous timer and set a timer to call our function 200ms (a fifth of a second) later. If the user doesn't press another key, 200ms later we do our call; but if they do, the timer gets canceled (again), and we schedule a new one.

---

Side note: The above assumes you have only `.form-control`, as appears to be the case in your code. But suppose you had several, and the information about what to do in the `get` was stored on the `.form-control`s? The above would be inappropriate, because typing in one of them, hitting tab to go to the next, and then typing in the next would prevent the first ever doing its work.

In that case, you'd store the timer handle on the element itself, using jQuery's `data`:

```
$('.form-control').keypress(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        timer = $this.data("keypress-timer");
    clearTimeout(timer); // clearTimeout will ignore `undefined`, so this is fine the first time
    timer = setTimeout(handleKeypress.bind(null, $this), 200);
});
function handleKeypress(control) {
    var container = control.closest(".container");
    var origin = container.find(".origin");
    var destination = container.find(".destination");
    var directions = container.find(".directions");
    var o = origin.val();
    var d = destination.val();

    control.data("keypress-timer", 0);

    directions.html('Wait, please...');

    $.get('/search', { origin: o, destination: d })
        .done(function(data) {
            container.find('.origin-info').html(o);
            container.find('.destination-info').html(d);

            directions.html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that that's just a hypothetical example, assuming these are in some kind of container and you can find the other relevant fields in that same container...

Comment: Beat me to it! OP: This is called a `debounce` but you should also look up `throttle` which may be useful for other similar situations. You may also want to look into the `input` event.

Comment: Corrected myself instead!

Comment: @BillCriswell should I look that all up as JavaScript or jQuery concepts? Are those indeed concepts or tools or functions or what? A quick Google search didn't gave me straight forward answers as those you'd get by searching just "jquery get" or "how to make a burrito".

Comment: I always thought of them as programming concepts in general but I learned about it through this post some time ago: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: @dabadaba: "[debounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce)" and "throttle" are both general engineering terms. "Debounce" comes from hardware electronics: A physical switch usually doesn't just instantly go from being off to being on, as the contacts approach each other there can be all kinds of intermittent half-connections. There's also physical bounce in a lot of switches. So "debouncing" a circuit is basically adding parts (capacitors, in simple circuits) that smooth out the bouncing so you get a clear off-to-on and on-to-off transition rather than lots of unclear ones.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder concerning the use of several `.form-control`s, I don't get where the problem would be. I indeed have two, and it works just fine. I guess your concern is that the timeout wouldn't by shared by all input elements, but I don't see what the big deal is about this issue, and I wouldn't call resetting the timer before the given time precisely an issue in this particular case).

Comment: @dabadaba: If they share a timer, they'll interfere with each other. Say you have inputs A and B. I type something in A, hit tab, and start typing in B. We never do a `get` for the stuff in A! I started typing in B within 200ms of typing in A, so that callback got cancelled. There are use cases for a shared timer, and use cases for a timer-per-element, so I figured I should mention both.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure starting typing in B before the timeout will cancel the request, the same than it would be canceled if you just kept typing in A. For me both situations are the same. I don't get why I should see one of them as an issue and the other as what's expected.

Comment: @dabadaba: Because you want the action related to A to happen. If you **don't** want the action related to A to happen, yes, they can share a timer. But normally, you do, and if you do then they can't share a timer.